# Angularjs app does not open the configured modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an application with angularjs where I need to show a page and then open a modal window with details when user pastes the url.

The router configuration is as follows:

```js
.state('main.legalentitites', {
    url: '/products/{productId:string}',
    views: {
        'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/productdetail.html',
            controller: 'productDetailCtrl',
        },
    },
})
.state('main.products.add', {
    url: '/products/{productId:string}/add',
    onEnter: function($state, $modal) {
        $modal
            .open({
                templateUrl: 'app/views/productModal.html',
                resolve: {},
                controller: 'ProductCtrl',
            })
            .result.then(function(result) {
                if (result) {
                    return $state.transitionTo('main.products')
                }
            })
    },
})
.$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location) {
    var $state = $injector.get('$state')
    $state.go('main.home')
})
```

When I enter the url `https://localhost:44821/products/6cbc799a-fdc8-4e4d-ac27-0a5165423641/add`, it does not navigate to the page and the modal does not open. There are no errors in the console either. It always goes to the otherwise configured part. What could be the issue?

Comment: if you are using one of the latest versions of ui-bootstrap for you modal, the service name changed from "$modal" to "$uibModal".

Comment: i am using older version still

Comment: When you enter the `https://localhost:44821/products/6cbc799a-fdc8-4e4d-ac27-0a5165423641` url (without `add`), does everything work as expected?

Comment: @arcquim yes it works

Comment: Could you create a Plunker or JSFiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) says:

> '/user/:id' - Matches '/user/bob' or '/user/1234!!!' or even '/user/' but not '/user' or '/user/bob/details'. The second path segment will be captured as the parameter 'id'.

and:

> '/user/{id}' - Same as the previous example, but using curly brace syntax.

So I suggest you to change the url from '/products/{productId:string}/add' to '/products/add/{productId:string}'. It should work.